# How achieve a page-change proof player?

Tags: web-development

I am interested in develloping a web music player similar to the soundcloud one

However, I can't figure out one thing: How player like soundclou one (and some other one) can "resist" a page change, continue playing without any latency, even if the page in the background is loading, the player is here and continue his job without any lag at the momment we click links. The only way to stop it is to reload the page with the browser

How can this be achieved? Does this used using a particular language and site architecture that center the player? If not, does any language / framework offers possibility to do thing like that?

EDIT:

So I made a Few search, and I get the following Idea:

- Pjax : That allow you to reload only certain content.
- HTML5 History API : The API Behind PJax
- One-page APP : Much harder. But using Ajax it could work.

Are these solution good? Wich one would be easier/ Better? Are there other alternative?

Comment: Persisting a player across multiple “pages” is trivial when using a [Single-Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). When a link is clicked, parts of the DOM are swapped out, instead of reloading the whole document. The player would then be situated in those parts of the page that don't get replaced.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]